# How to update all rows in subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to update a field in a sub form based on a factor from the main form however only one record is being updated. My code is:

```
Private Sub Text54_AfterUpdate()
Me.pack_details![Text64] = Me.pack_details![Text68] * 1.07 / Me![xchange_rate] 
End Sub
```

How would I make this apply to all the rows in the sub form? Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details. Which controls are bound? Are you using a normal subform, a continuous subform, or a subform in datasheet view?

Comment: So when I access the properties it does state it is a Continuous Form under the Default View and all the controls are bound

Answer (score 0):

Try Requerying for the data after the change:

```
Me.Subform.Requery
```

in your case assuming Text54 is in the master form:

```
Private Sub Text54_AfterUpdate()
    Me.pack_details![Text64] = Me.pack_details![Text68] * 1.07 / Me![xchange_rate] 
    Me.Subform.Requery
End Sub
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/subform-requery-method-access)

Comment: That won't work. You should requery when making changes to the underlying data, but not when making changes to controls on the form itself.

Comment: If the form contents are driven off of Text54, like SELECT * From SubTable where FieldA = [Text54.value] type situation it would rerun this query and get the updated dataset rows would it not?

Comment: Eh... Yes, maybe, but that's not what this question is about. The question is about changing all records on a subform, not a subform not updating after changing one record.

Comment: I think we may need more clarification (as you asked for). As I understand it the problem is a Main form field is getting changed; "based on a factor from the main form." And the subform needs be be updated after this change; "I'm trying to update a field in a sub form based on a factor from the main"

Comment: Yes the main form is being updated and is used in a calculation in the subform which does update but only the first row or which ever is currently selected/clicked

Comment: @atsai100 Did the `Me.Subform.Requery` work for you? If so please mark the question as answered, if not please comment on it and edit your question with any additional information on your attempts.

Comment: @Evan I actually get a compile error: method or data member not found

Comment: Try `Me.[SubformNameAsString].Form.Requery` or `Me.[SubformNameAsString].Requery`

Comment: That gave me no errors but it is still only updating one

Comment: @atsai100 Look into using Reload after the requery, it might cover what the requery misses